# Perform an API request to produce a random image/link of golden dog

Tags: api

I am quite new in using API and have been trying to perform an API request to produce random image/link of golden dog but keep getting all images. this is the url im using: https://dog.ceo/api/breed/retriever/golden/images

Hope you guys are able to help.